# Manipulating JPEG images pixel-per-pixel using Mini Jpeg Decoder

Tags: c++, image-manipulation, libjpeg, getpixel

I want to manipulate JPEG images with C++ using the decoder *[Mini Jpeg Decoder](http://www.h4ck3r.net/2009/12/02/mini-jpeg-decoder/)*.

**The problem is:** I want to read pixel per pixel, but the decoder only returns an imageData-array, similar as **[libjpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg)** does.

**I can't make a method like this:**

```
char getPixel(char x, char y, unsigned char* imageData) 
{
    //...???
}
```

The return (the `char` variable) should contain the luminance of the pixel.

(I work with grayscale images...)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the `Decoder` class delivers a byte array of color values with the `GetImage()` method. So you could write a function that looks like this:

```
char getLuminance(Decoder* dec, int x, int y) {
    if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= dec->GetWidth() || y >= dec->GetHeight()) {
        throw "out of bounds";
    }

    return dec->GetImage()[x + y * dec->GetWidth()];
}
```

I'm uncertain of the pixel layout, so maybe the array access is not right. Also this only works for grey-scale images, or else you would get the luminance of the Red color value at the position only. HTH